# Setting up a group with all of my friends, 4,800

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to set up a group in facebook for all of my 4,800 friends?

If not, what is the largest number that can be in a group? I just started a new group and facebook would only allow me to have 15 friends in it. How do I set up a group with more than 15?

Comment: As far as I am aware you should be able to do this.  Did you receive any error message?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps set it up as a fan page would work for you.